# Searching for math encyclopedia with inventor / date / source by topic.

Tags: math-history

I remember to have seen an encyclopedia-type-of mathematics book that describes for each topic contained in it when and by who it was invented or when it was first mentioned. I.e. quaternion: Hamilton, Ireland, 1843 ( probably the tree anecdote as well. ) I tried Google Books, Amazon, Google, the Open University Library search, but I can't find it anymore.

Does anyone know which book it could have been? ( It does exist! It was written for an undergraduate audience, if I remember well. )

Comment: What's the tree anecdote? I only know of [Brougham Bridge](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/node24.html).

Comment: The same, I thought he carved it on a tree, but it was on a bridge, wasn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book I was looking for is http://books.google.nl/books?id=MfKKMSuthacC&dq=encyclopedia+of+mathematics+james+tanton&source=gbs_navlinks_s The Encyclopedia of Mathematics by James Tanton.

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to this:

[Mathematics 1001: Absolutely Everything That Matters About Mathematics in 1001 Bite-Sized Explanations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1554077192)

Comment: Not that I recall by name, and I can't preview it on Google books. I vividly remember a comprehensive list of concepts followed by when it first appeared in the literature.

Comment: Seen that book now, it is not it, alas.